# How can I make a list that contains an anonymous object?

Tags: c#

I created the following code:

```
var header = "Entity Validation Error";
var detail = < I want to have a list that contains the title and errors list here>
foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
{
    var title = string.Format("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\"
                has the following validation errors:",
        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(title);
    var errors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
    {
        var error = string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
        errors.Add(error);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, 
         < I want to return the header and detail as an anonymous object >);
```

It goes through each of my entity errors, prints a debug message, creates a title and a list of details.

How can I take the variable title and errors as an anonymous object and put this into a list so that I can return them?

Comment: Well, "`return < I want to return the header and detail as an anonymous object >`"  suggests a fundamental problem; by definition *returning* an anonymous object is not possible, except as `object` - which isn't very useful to any caller. If you want to *return* it, ***why*** do you want it to be anonymous?

Comment: I have other places in my code that return an anonymous object. The object is sent to a web front end and then json is used to read the contents.

Comment: I agree with Marc, just create a simple class and add that to a list.  it'll be well defined and clearer on maintenance.

Comment: Melina, show code where you return anonymous objects. Do you want to convert them to Json?

Comment: I added the last line. That code will convert what is there inside the <> to JSON before sending it back to the web front end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I make a list in C# that contains an anonymous object?

Well, one lazy way is: as `object`:

```
var list = new List<object>();
//...
list.Add(new { Foo = 123, Bar = "abc" });
```

that isn't very useful, though. So perhaps the question is "how to make a list typed by an anonymous type"; slightly trickier - you kinda need to use an instance to convince the compiler to inject the T:

```
var list = Enumerable.Repeat(new { Foo = 123, Bar = "abc" }, 0).ToList();
//...
list.Add(new { Foo = 456, Bar = "def" });
```

(note that the list in the top line is empty; that fake instance is just a template for the compiler)

But again, this is still best kept local. You then say "I want to return" - now *there* is where it gets really problematic. Basically, you can't return it *typed*. You can return `object`, or the non-generic `IList` - but not as the anonymous type, so nothing useful to the caller.

Basically, at this point I would say: "don't". Instead, *create a regular type*, and expose it *as that type*. Anonymous types do not work well outside of the method that creates them (with small caveats like data-binding and serialization, where it is ok).

Comment: It *is* usable by the caller (sort of) - see this from TomasP http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx

Comment: @MikeGoodwin yes, the infamous "cast by example" - frankly, this is insanely brittle - there are no good use-cases for this. If the caller (or some downstream code) wants to cast them later, then it shouldn't have been anonymous in the first place. As I noted in the answer, I'd forgive things that *don't* depend on this - for example, serializers and data-binding. Cast by example: considered harmful.

Comment: Agreed. That is why is said it is "sort of" usable.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type. Similarly, you cannot declare
>   a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as
>   having an anonymous type. To pass an anonymous type, or a collection
>   that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can
>   declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the
>   purpose of strong typing. If you must store query results or pass them
>   outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct
>   or class instead of an anonymous type.

This practically summarizes what have been said in the comments. If you need to return something from the method then it's a part of the class's interface. An interface returning an enigmatic *object* is not very clear and readable to it's client, and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public List<dynamic> GetAnonymousList()
{
   var list = new List<dynamic>()
    {
       new { Foo = 123, Bar = "abc" },
       new { Foo = 456, Bar = "def" }
    };

    return list;
}
```

In the caller you can then do:

```
int fooSum = GetAnonymousList().Sum(item => item.Foo);
IEnumerable<string> bars = GetAnonymousList().Select(item => (string)item.Bar);
```

Although this is probably as bad in practise as returning a `List<object>` and then casting it back to the original anonymous type using the trick described by Tomas Petricek:

http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx

As other answers have said: If you need to return it, then it is better to define a proper type/interface for the items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something liek this

```
  public List<T> CreateList<T>(T itemOftype)
  {
     List<T> newList = new List<T>();
     return newList;
  } 

   var error = new { Header= "AVBC", Details = "Details" };
   var errorList = CreateList(error );

   errorList.Add(new { Header= "AVBC_BCGBD", Details = "Details_SBNJHJH" }
```

You can also create an array of annonymous object and call `ToList()` method

Answer (score 0):

All of the answes so far seem to have missed that what you actually want to do is return `JSON` from something that looks a lot like a `wep.api` method.

But based on the list of overloads for the `Request.CreateErrorResponse` method (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) it seems like you will not be able to simply have your anonymous type returned from your code.

Instead you must use one of the existing overloads for the method. Maybe you could actually return it as a preformatted string, or maybe you could try to use the overload with a `ModelStateDictionary` (not sure if it will work or how difficult it would be)?

But since there is no overload taking an `object` (and no generic overload either as opposed to `Request.CreateResponse`) you cannot do exactly what you want.